# I am not sure why decision tree and random forest is displaying 100% accuracy?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I am currently working on a model that reads structured data and determines if someone has a disease. I think the issue is the data is not being split between training and testing data. I am unaware of how I would be able to do that.

I am not sure what to try.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier



heart_data = pd.read_csv('cardio_train.csv')

heart_data.head()

heart_data.shape

heart_data.describe()

heart_data.isnull().sum()

heart_data_columns = heart_data.columns

predictors = heart_data[heart_data_columns[heart_data_columns != 'target']]  # all columns except Breast Cancer
target = heart_data['target']  # Breast Cancer column


#This function returns the first n rows for the object based on position. It is useful for quickly testing if your object has the right type
predictors.head()
target.head()

#normalize the data by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.

predictors_norm = (predictors - predictors.mean()) / predictors.std()
predictors_norm.head()



n_cols = predictors_norm.shape[1]  # number of predictors


def regression_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    #inputs
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu')) # activation function
    model.add(Dense(1))

    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    #loss measures the results and figures out how bad it did. Optimizer generates next guess.
    return model


# build the model
model = regression_model()
print (model)
# fit the model
history=model.fit(predictors_norm, target, validation_split=0.3, epochs=10, verbose=2)


#Decision Tree
print ("Processing Decision Tree")
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc.fit(predictors_norm,target)
print("Decision Tree Test Accuracy {:.2f}%".format(dtc.score(predictors_norm, target)*100))


#Support Vector Machine
print ("Processing Support Vector Machine")
svm = SVC(random_state = 1)
svm.fit(predictors_norm, target)
print("Test Accuracy of SVM Algorithm: {:.2f}%".format(svm.score(predictors_norm,target)*100))

#Random Forest
print ("Processing Random Forest")
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 1)
rf.fit(predictors_norm, target)
print("Random Forest Algorithm Accuracy Score : {:.2f}%".format(rf.score(predictors_norm,target)*100))
```

The message i am getting is this
Decision Tree Test Accuracy 100.00%
However, support vector machine is getting 73.37%

Comment: Yes, you haven't splitted the data into testing and training so you overfitted it.

Comment: As for the "how to do that", have a look at sklearn [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: What would be the syntax to fix this issue? I have been googling however, there is so many different versions and I would not know where to be the variables after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are evaluating your model on the same data as when you trained it : you are probably **overfitting**. To overcome this, you must separate the data into two parts, one for learning, one for testing :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(predictors, target, test_size=0.2)
```

Then, learn your model with the train dataset and evaluate it on the test dataset :

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc.fit(x_train, y_train)
accuracy = dtc.score(x_test, y_test) * 100
print(f"Decision Tree test accuracy : {accuracy} %.")
```